# Concurrent request on commerce checkout

Tags: commerce

From some days I worked on one of issue related to drupal commerce services,

While two customers add in the same time a product whose the stock was only 1 in that case two order successfully completed. How this could happen?

Can anyone suggest there be a check in the code of the basket to avoid one of these 2 customers to add the same product?